# Totient function inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I am not quite sure how to approach this problem:

If a and n are such natural numbers that a divides n, then $n-ϕ(n)\ge a-ϕ(a)$

This is my thought process so far: Obviously the fact that $n=n*a$ should be used. If n is prime, then $n-ϕ(n)=a-ϕ(a)=1$ because only n and 1 could then possibly be a. If n is not prime, but a is, then $n-ϕ(n)>1$ and $a-ϕ(a)=1$ so $n-ϕ(n)>a-ϕ(a)=1$. Yet I am not sure what happens if both a and n are not prime.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $\varphi(m)$ counts the numbers from $1$ to $m$ that are relatively prime to $m$. It follows that $m-\varphi(m)$ counts the numbers from $1$ to $m$ that are **not** relatively prime to $m$.

Let $n=ka$. If $1\le x\le a$, and $x$ is not relatively prime to $a$, then $x$ is a number between $1$ and $n$ that is not relatively prime to $n$. The result follows.

Comment: @ Andre\'e Nicolas: I don't understand you fully. Take $a=14, n =3\times 14=42$. But gcd$(20,42)>1$, yet 20 is not 3 times any number.

Comment: Consider the surjective (ring) homomorphism: $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}\to \mathbf{Z}/a\mathbf{Z}$. Number of inverse images is the same for all elements  of the codomain (by surjectivity) and is equal to $n/a$.  But a non-unit can go to a unit under this map. For example 3 is a non-unit for 75 but a unit for 25.

Comment: Take $a=14$ and $n=42$. What I said is that if $x$ is **not** relatively prime to $14$, then $3x$ is not relatively prime to $42$. The $3$ is not the relevant thing in the counting, $x$ is. One could instead have used plain $x$. I will replace $kx$ by $x$. Does the same thing.